# No city names displayed on openlayers vectortiles

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector-tiles

[image]I followed the example on https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/openlayers/ and I don't know why e.g. why city names are not expanded. Rather than that the placeholders are still displayed. I also got an own api key for openmaptiles.org but still this doesn't change.

Has anyone an idea on what could be wrong?

I set up a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/f55e5umx/ and using the style at

```
https://openmaptiles.github.io/klokantech-basic-gl-style/style-cdn.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `{name:en}` is not supported when converting a style.json into openlayers styles. Maybe try using BoundlessGeo's [olms](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style) instead of the openmaptiles version?

It certainly looks like the hosted [example](https://openmaptiles.github.io/klokantech-basic-gl-style/#12.24/47.3718/8.5481) uses simply `{name}` in the [style.json](https://github.com/openmaptiles/klokantech-basic-gl-style/blob/master/style.json).